# Big commerce stick nav bar menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bigcommerce

I am working on big commerce website,and i want stick menu on scroll,I have used bootstrap to achieve that with css but its not working fine,Here is my code

```
<div id="top-nav">
        <div class="CategoryList" id="TopCategoryList" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="197" >
            <div class="SideCategoryListClassic">
                <ul class="category-list" style="padding-top: 3px;">
                    <li class=""><a href="/motorcycle-tire-warmers">MOTO-D Tire Warmers</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="/pro-series-motorcycle-stands">MOTO-D Stands</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="/cnc-motorcycle-parts">Bonamici Rearsets</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="/motorcycle-gps-lap-timer">MOTO-D "Next" GPS Lap Timer</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="/motorcycle-undersuits-and-baselayers">MOTO-D Undersuit</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="/spark-italy-exhaust-technologies">Spark Italy Exhausts</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="/performance-riding-motorcycle-accessories">Accessories</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
#top-nav.affix {
  background-color: #333;
  left: 0;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2222;
```

}

[This is my dummy site](http://motodummygmailcom6.mybigcommerce.com/?ctk=S5IH79487W1BH6L17GBF0)

Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: isn't the navbar already fixed to the top?

Comment: Yes sir it is,But if you look at my dummy site,While scrolling  it doesnt give a smooth scroll  http://motodummygmailcom6.mybigcommerce.com/?ctk=S5IH79487W1BH6L17GBF0

Comment: so you want a smooth transition?

Comment: Yes sir i want that it to be smooth transition

Comment: youre gonna have to redesign your navbar to work with bootstrap affix cause there's no way you can align everything correctly using css

Comment: Can i achieve this with jquery or javascript?without redesigning the navbar

Comment: you can try sticky.js plugin developed with jquery.  it's pretty easy and straight forward to use

Comment: <script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.sticky.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sticker").sticky({topSpacing:0});
  });
</script> this is the code i have found

Comment: put an id inside your navbar then inside your js file just add $("#sticker").sticky({topSpacing:0}); });  Make sure you have jquery.sticky.js or at least the cdn version.

Comment: Can you please provide me little guidance? Here id is top-nav,Above is the whole code

Comment: $("#top-nav").sticky({topSpacing:0}); })

Comment: can you help me write a script?I want   title-bar dispay:none for affix class and want to display  title-bar when class is affix-top,This classes are changing with page scroll

Comment: $('.affix').css({
    display: 'none'
  
});
$('.affix-top').css({
    display: 'block'
  
});
This is i wrote

Answer (score 0):

This is coming to CSS3 but it's not available yet. You can read more about `position: sticky` [here](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-position-3/#sticky-pos).

In the meantime, I would use some JavaScript to make this a smooth transition.

*I'm just guessing with the scrollTop number, so adjust it as needed.*

## **JQUERY**

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 60) {
   $('top-nav').addClass('fixed');
}
else {
   $('top-nav').removeClass('fixed');
}
```

});

You can do the same thing in plain ole JavaScript as well, but since you are already loading jQuery, might as well use it!

Comment: $('.affix').css({
    display: 'none'
  
});
$('.affix-top').css({
    display: 'block'